# Angular 5 Cannot PUT with 401 Errors

Tags: javascript, angular, express

I'd like to update data with using PUT Method on my angular service and express routes, but it give me 401 error. This is my service :

```
//401
makeAdmin(_id) {
  this.loadToken()
  let headers = new Headers()
  headers.append('Authorization', this.authToken)
  console.log(_id)
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json')
  return this.http.put(this.baseUri+'users/makeAdmin/'+_id,{headers: headers})
    .map(res => res.json())
}
```

But when I'm using `GET` or `DELETE` Method, it can send data to my express routes. This is my express route :

```
router.put('/makeAdmin/:id',passport.authenticate('jwt', {session:false}),(req, res, next)=>{
    console.log(req.params.id)
})
```

My browser log error :

> PUT http://localhost:8080/users/makeAdmin/5b57219f1e1be6279c95a5be 401
>   (Unauthorized) core.js:1440 ERROR Response {_body: "Unauthorized",
>   status: 401, ok: false, statusText: "Unauthorized", headers:
>   Headers, …}

EDITED This is from console.log :

> Response {_body: "Unauthorized", status: 401, ok: false, statusText:
>   "Unauthorized", headers: Headers, …} headers : Headers {_headers:
>   Map(0), _normalizedNames: Map(0)} ok : false status : 401 statusText :
>   "Unauthorized" type : 2 url :
>   "http://localhost:8080/users/makeAdmin/5b57219f1e1be6279c95a5be"
>   _body : "Unauthorized"
>   **proto** : Body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `map` and `Headers` instead of `HttpHeaders`, I assume that you are using angular's old `Http` client, instead of the new `HttpClient` class.

The PUT method needs a body ([documentation](https://angular.io/api/http/Http#put)), so try this

```
return this.http.put(this.baseUri+'users/makeAdmin/'+_id, null, {headers: headers})
.map(res => res.json())
```

If you don't specify `null` as the body, then the headers are sent as the body parameter, and the options parameter with the actual headers is left empty.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
let headers = new Headers().append('Authorization', this.authToken);
```

From the HttpHeaders docs: Immutable set of Http headers, with lazy parsing.

https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders

Comment: What user has mentioned is also correct. You are just re-writing it in single line.

Comment: No..headers are immutable, I edited to add more info

Comment: I've changed as yours, but still give me 401 response

Comment: Is the token present or valid, when sending with the request?

Comment: The token is valid, I've check local storage, and tried to re-login to make another token, but still 401. The GET and DELETE works in this case, but POST and PUT, gives me 401.

Comment: FYI, `HttpHeaders` class is immutable, but `Headers` is not

Comment: in your passport config. Do you have something like this?
ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();